# Is linear convergence norm invariant?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|_a,\|\cdot\|_b$ be two norms on $\Bbb R^n$ and $(x^k)_{k\in\Bbb N}\subset \Bbb R^n$ a sequence such that there exists $0<\alpha <1$ with
$ \|x^{k+1}\|_a \leq \alpha \|x^k\|_a$ for all $k\in \Bbb N.$
Does it implies the existence of $0<\beta<1$ such that $\|x^{k+1}\|_b \leq \beta \|x^k\|_b$ for all $k\in \Bbb N$?

I noticed that we unfortunately can't use directly the fact that every norms are equivalent on finitie dimensional space. Moreover we can build example where $\alpha =\beta$ would implies a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an easy counterexample for $n=2$ is $x^k = (2^{-k},0)$ for even $n$, and $x^k = (0,2^{-k})$ for odd $n$ with $\| \cdot \|_a$ being the standard norm. Then your assumption is satisfied with $\alpha = 1/2$. Now with the norm $\|(x_1, x_2)\|_b = \sqrt{x_1^2 + 4x_2^2}$ you have $\|x^k\|_b = \|x^{k+1}\|_b$ for all even $k$.

Comment: very nice :). Thanks a lot!